# bin/www app.listen is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run my server from `www` file but when trying to run it gives me following output. Why I'm getting this error?

I'm using Express 4.16. Is there some problem with node env path? Or it's some other issue?

```
❯ ./bin/www                                                                               ✔ master
/Users/me/Test/ExpressAPP/bin/www:6
app.listen(3000, function () {
    ^

TypeError: app.listen is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Test/ExpressAPP/bin/www:6:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:607:3
```

**./bin/www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('./../app')

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port 300')
})
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.send('OK')
})

module.exports = app
```

Comment: show your app file.

Comment: @aircraft edited check now

Comment: ohh sorry its' app

Comment: a bit of a copy past error...Edited but yaa that's my app file @qqilihq

Comment: According to the error, you have the wrong/no file. log `app` after you require it, see what comes out.

Comment: @KfirM it shows  `{}`

Comment: From what you provide my best guess is the path (`./../app`) is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet there is no problem with your code. I created a demo with your code snippet. I works as expected. So the issue maybe related to your environment. Can you try delete the **node_modules** folder and try to reinstall npm packages with `npm i -S express` command?

And I have two idea help you to resolve your issue.

- Add `cosole.log(app)` in **www** file and see what the app that you've required is. Is it the same object as you created in **app.js**?
- Double-check your source code is same as what you pasted, especially the `module.exports = app`. I've lost the **s** before.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
/* config/express.js */
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function() {
  var app = express();
  app.set('port', 3000);
  return app;
};


/* server.js */
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./config/express')(); // Notice the additional () here

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Express Server Runing on port"+ app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: but how does that fix my issue?

Comment: In the javascript, a function can be treated like a class.

Comment: but this doesn't work. I get same error in ./bin/www saying app.listen doesn't exist

Comment: also i know function can be treated like a class. But what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

```
wrong: module.export=app;  

 right: module.exports=app;
```